# Split infinitive with modal verb "have" or something else?

Tags: word-order, infinitives

We have a phrase: "Besides, Seth had an afternoon guided fishing trip to run that began at 3 pm, during the hottest part of the day."

Explain please the grammar sentence construction, especially the first part. Is that split infinitive "Seth had ..... to run" and "had" is there a modal verb?

If I rephrase it to "Seth had to run an afternoon guided fishing trip that began at 3 pm" will it have the same meaning like original sentence?
As I know split infinitive used when between participle "to" and "verb" is an adverb... correct me please if I'm not right

Comment: Where did you find the example sentence?

Comment: This is not a split infinitive. In a split infinitive, there is a word or phrase *after* the word "to" and before the associated infinitive; e.g. "to effectively run".

Answer (score 6):

> > Seth had a trip to run
>
> Is *had* a modal verb with the same meaning as *Seth had to run a trip*?

No; the infinitival *to run* is in this case actually an adjunct modifying *trip*, designating an assigned or expected future action: the same construction appears in contexts other than *have*:

> I can't come tonight: my boss handed me a report *to finish* by first thing in the morning.
>   She's bored and looking for something *to do*.
>   I bought some doughnuts *to take* to work.

But your conjecture is a shrewd one: *HAVE Obj to VERB* is in fact believed to be the construction out of which the quasi-modal construction *HAVE to VERB* developed.

Comment: Thank you very much! could you pls give a link or a name of that grammar topic to read about it more... if it´s possible

Comment: @AlexeyKutsenko Is [this](http://faculty.arts.ubc.ca/lbrinton/HAVETO.PDF) --see particularly §§2.2 and 3--the sort of thing you want?

Comment: It might be worth noting that "split infinitive" usually refers to a separation between the "to" and the base verb: to boldly go, to quickly run, to carefully consider, to cautiously suggest.  The only infinitive in the example sentence is "to run", and there is nothing to split the "to" from the "run".

Comment: Despite having [asked about the usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/37742/) on ELU some years ago, I'd never consciously recognised that HAVE to (="must") VERB probably derives from HAVE Obj to VERB. Perhaps it's significant that many/most of us usually prefer to blur that historical link by the ***haff / hat*** pronunciations. It's like we *want* it to be a completely different word. Perhaps because the alternative ***must*** is so syntactically screwed up (consider *I must to London tonight!*, where ***go*** would have been "optional" since at least Shakespeare's time).

Comment: FWIW, I found 92 written instances of [*I have to pick a bone with (you)*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+have+to+pick+a+bone+with%22) and 10 of [*I must pick a bone with you*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+must+pick+a+bone+with%22) They all sound "facetious" to me, but they're dwarfed by an estimated 7000+ hits for [*I have a bone to pick with you*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22I+have+a+bone+to+pick+with%22) anyway. That one presumably survives as a "frozen form", despite an overall trend towards a different sequence.